# Map matching not working, When coordinates are inside home or office, Where missing road in OSM data

Tags: python, algorithm, geolocation, map-matching, project-valhalla

My aim is to create a map-making algorithm. So I have GPS data of user travel, Valhalla map matching is perfect solution for my use case, But where GPS track route inside home, office or parking slot, Then Valhalla map matching provide the nearest road.

Before Map Matching
[image]

After Map Matching
[image]
So, After Map matching yellow highways tracking is perfect So that is not issued, But inside green area (garden) many straight lines shows, And that is not I'm assuming, Is there any solution available where Inside the green area (garden) Also shows some of the coordinates which are not noisy.

So basically need to combination of Valhalla map matching and some noisy coordinates' removal.

Any solution?

I tried using the Valhalla output and oringinal coordinates. If enough nearby coordinates are identified in the original, the Noisy method will eliminate the noisy coordinates and replace them with output that map matches the Valhalla.

Here is code, Please review it

```
import requests
import json
from geoJsonToCoords import geoJsonToCoords
from common import extractCoordinates, haversineDistance, saveIntoJSFile
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np

df_rawGPS_points = geoJsonToCoords('./example/1.geojson')
meili_coordinates = df_rawGPS_points.to_json(orient='records')
meili_head = '{"shape":'
meili_tail = ""","search_radius": 300, "shape_match":"map_snap", "costing":"auto", "format":"osrm"}"""
meili_request_body = meili_head + meili_coordinates + meili_tail
url = "http://localhost:8002/trace_route"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = str(meili_request_body)
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

if r.status_code == 200:
    response_text = json.loads(r.text)
    # a = valhalla, b= orignal
    valhalla_c, original_c = extractCoordinates(
        df_rawGPS_points, response_text)
    a = original_c
    b = valhalla_c
    print("a>>", valhalla_c, len(valhalla_c))
    print("b>>", original_c, len(original_c))

    all_coordinates = np.array(a + b)

    eps = 0.05
    min_samples = 2

    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples, metric=haversineDistance)
    labels = dbscan.fit_predict(np.radians(all_coordinates))

    cluster_counts = {}
    for label in labels:
        if label != -1:
            cluster_counts[label] = cluster_counts.get(label, 0) + 1

    high_density_clusters = [label for label,
                            count in cluster_counts.items() if count > 2]

    result = []

    for coord_a, coord_b, label in zip(a, b, labels):
        if label in high_density_clusters:
            result.append(coord_b)
        else:
            result.append(coord_a)

    print("result >>>", result)
    saveIntoJSFile(result)
```

And Functions are

```
def extractCoordinates(df_rawGPS_points, response):
    import pandas as pd
    import json

    resp = str(response['tracepoints'])
    resp = resp.replace("'waypoint_index': None", "'waypoint_index': '#'")
    resp = resp.replace(
        "None", "{'matchings_index': '#', 'name': '', 'waypoint_index': '#', 'alternatives_count': 0, 'distance': 0, 'location': [0.0, 0.0]}")

    resp = resp.replace("'", '"')
    resp = json.dumps(resp)
    resp = json.loads(resp)
    df_response = pd.read_json(resp)
    df_response = df_response[['name', 'distance', 'location']]
    df_trip_optimized = pd.merge(
        df_rawGPS_points, df_response, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    a = [coord[::-1] for coord in df_trip_optimized['location'].tolist()]
    b = df_trip_optimized[['lat', 'lon']].values.tolist()
    return a, b


def haversineDistance(coord1, coord2):
    from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, atan2
    R = 6371.0
    lat1, lon1 = coord1
    lat2, lon2 = coord2
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c

    return distance


def dtwDistance(seq1, seq2):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
    n, m = len(seq1), len(seq2)
    cost = np.inf * np.ones((n, m))

    cost[0, 0] = euclidean(seq1[0], seq2[0])
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, m):
            cost[i, j] = euclidean(seq1[i], seq2[j]) + \
                min(cost[i-1, j], cost[i, j-1], cost[i-1, j-1])

    return cost[-1, -1]
```

Comment: where is the code ?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L Please check it again!!